# Does the 2019 UA artificer need to prepare the Lesser Restoration spell to cast it with their Alchemical Mastery feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, unearthed-arcana, spellcasting, artificer

The 2019 UA Artificer's Alchemist subclass gains the following ability as part of their [Alchemical Mastery](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf#page=7) feature at 6th level:

> In addition, you can cast *lesser restoration* without expending a spell slot, provided you use alchemist’s supplies as the spellcasting focus. You can do so a number of times per day equal to your Intelligence modifier (minimum of once).

Do I need to prepare *Lesser Restoration* as one of my spells for the day in order to use this feature, or does this ability allow me to cast it a limited number of times without preparing it?

Comment: I've edited the DDB link to point directly to the UA instead, since the content on the linked DDB page will likely change in a few months when the artificer is published (resulting in a confusing reading experience), whereas the UA PDF will remain as-is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## You don't have to prepare *lesser restoration*

The Alchemical Mastery feature is granting you a separate way to cast *lesser restoration*. It is independent of the Alchemist spellcasting feature.

It is similar to, and may well be explained by comparison with, Warlocks' Mystic Arcanum.

> Choose one 6th-level spell from the warlock spell list as this arcanum.
> You can cast your arcanum spell once without expending a spell slot. You must finish a long rest before you can do so again.

Note that the Warlock does not learn the spell from this feature, and that there is no way for a Warlock to learn 6th level warlock spells using their spellcasting feature. The feature grants a way to cast the spell without knowing (ie. having learned/prepared) the spell.

If Alchemical Mastery was intended to require *lesser restoration* to be prepared, it could (and probably should) be phrased differently, for instance along the lines of Wizards' Spell Mastery:

> Choose a 1st-level wizard spell and a 2nd-level wizard spell that are in your spellbook. You can cast those spells at their lowest level without expending a spell slot when you have them prepared.